# How do I check if any of the current document type's ancestors are a specific type in Umbraco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco

I'm trying to write some logic which applies to pages of any of a group of document types in Umbraco.

I'd like to say 'is this document's type, or any of it's parent document types equal to a certain type', but I can't work out how to even get to the document type structure.

I tried using 'HasProperty' with a property defined on the parent to achieve the same effect (because the properties are inherited) - but if the property doesn't have a value, then HasProperty returns False (which seems broken to me, but apparently is just how it works).

Using Razor in Umbraco v6.1.5 (Assembly version: 1.0.4993.19246).

(For now I'll have to check if the NodeTypeAlias is in a big list I suppose).

Comment: Even a default value in a property would do it. Then on my parent I could have a property which is always true for all children - but I don't think you can specify default values in Umbraco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve the `DocumentType` hierarchy from the published cache, i.e. from the `Node` or `IPublishedContent` objects.

However, what you could do is:

1. On application start generate a `Collection<DocumentType>` object of all the content (not media, member) `DocumentType` objects and cache it. I certainly wouldn't do this from the UI as querying the DocumentType will cause calls to the database, so caching and reusing the objects is much better.
2. Possibly add the same code to the AfterNew event of a `DocumentType`. This way new `DocumentType` objects are also added to the cached list.
3. Create an extension method like the existing `IsDocumentType(string documentTypeAlias)` which queries the cached list.

The following code will retrieve the parent structure, you just need to add a `while(docType.MasterContentType != null)` construct:

```
DocumentType docType = DocumentType.GetByAlias("ContentPage");
DocumentType parentDocType = new DocumentType(docType.MasterContentType);`
```

**Edit:**

If you want to go down the root of having a property on the `IPublishedContent` or `Node` instance then I would adopt a similar approach.

1. Have all doc types inherit from a single doc type which has a label property called `parentDocTypeAliases`.
2. On the `Newing` event of a `Document`, add the aliases of the parent doc types as a cmma delimited list to the `parentDocTypeAliases` property. You'll still need the code listed above to query the doc type hierarchy.
3. Create a new extension method (e.g. `InheritsFromDocumentType(string documentTypeAlias)`) that queries the csv value.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer - but maintenance overhead of that compared to just checking against a list of document types seems more. I'm really surprised that 'HasProperty' checks for a 'true' value rather than if it's defined - because that seems like a perfect, simple solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's six and two three's whether you have a property or interrogate a static list of document types, but I can see the advantage of having it in the properties.

Comment: Sorry, I just mean use a normal property: not set a property with the parent doc types. Because properties are inherited from parent document types, what I want to do is just check if a document has a property. But I can't because the default for a new document is that ALL checks for HasProperty return false. Apparently there are packages that will let me set a default value for a property on some document types - maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: Sorry what is a 'normal' property? Your question is specifically asking for any document "*is this document's type, or any of it's parent document types equal to a certain type*". I'm not sure why you are using `HasProperty()` as this is irrelevant to the problem. My solution is a perfectly valid approach and only a few lines of code too.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution isn't a way to solve the problem. Document types contain a set of properties. These are inherited to their children. So another way to check if a document is a certain type is to check it's properties - which are inherited so match in exactly the way I want. Without needing to write any code outside of the page. But you can't check for their existence.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer because it is a valid solution. But it's a more complicated approach than I'm prepared to use for this problem in my particular circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 'is this document's type, or any of it's parent document types equal to a certain type' with the following:

```
node.AncestorsOrSelf().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "your doctype alias");
```

This will return an IPublishedContent object of the first node it encounters of type "your doctype alias".

Source: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/querying

Comment: That will get the first node in the tree with the type specified. Not the first one with the type or any of it's parent types. Which is what I was looking for. I'm looking to query the document type hierarchy, not the content hierarchy (I can do that :))